# changing the color of UIView when scrolling table view ios

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

Hi I am getting data from `JSON`. I am showing that data in a `tableView`. The table view hex color was added to `UIView`. It showed properly, but when I scrolled 4 to 5 times the color changed. Other text remained the same. I don't know what's wrong.

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
  //values
  return subDataArray.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
  NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
  //values
  UIView *view = (UIView *)[cell viewWithTag:27];

  NSString *hexStr = [dic objectForKey:@"secolor"];
  unsigned int hexint = 0;
  // Create scanner
  NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:hexStr];
  // Tell scanner to skip the # character
  [scanner setCharactersToBeSkipped:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"#"]];
  [scanner scanHexInt:&hexint];
  view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:((CGFloat) ((hexint & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255 green:((CGFloat) ((hexint & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255 blue:((CGFloat) (hexint & 0xFF))/255 alpha:1]; 
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
  CGPoint offset = scrollView.contentOffset;
  CGRect bounds = scrollView.bounds;
  CGSize size = scrollView.contentSize;
  UIEdgeInsets inset = scrollView.contentInset;
  float y = offset.y + bounds.size.height - inset.bottom;
  float h = size.height;
  float reload_distance = 15;
  if(y > h + reload_distance) {
    //Call the Method to load More Data...
    page=page+1;  
    [self homeLoad];
    NSLog(@"TableView scrolling");
  }
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your whole `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method ? The part your provide cannot work at all.

Comment: i think this happens when you reuses the existing table-view cell, it replaces the color with current color. Instead of getting the view by tag , why not you getting as cell.view ???

Comment: @MichaëlAzevedo changed

Comment: @SibaPrasadHota can u tell me how to code cell.view ..I am coding like this     UIView *view = (UIView *)[cell viewWithTag:27];

Comment: Where does `dic` come from and why isn't `subDataArray` used since the number of rows depend of it ?

Comment: If you are creating custom cell through Storyboard or Xib , you need to create object for that view & connect it with fileowner. Then you can easily access it like cell.viewobject.

Comment: @SibaPrasadHota dynamic cell didnt allowed that I think

Comment: Actually this happen when I scroll and call the request to get the data from json..without that scroll calling function it was working.But I need to send request when the table view scroll and load other data from server.I am sending msg to server send me page by page.

Comment: in that case you have to Access the cell in `scrollViewDidScrol`  method and change the view color. Also you can  use the metod  `[tableview visiblerows`]..

Comment: @ras please show me here Your Hex color array for better understanding

Comment: @VvkAghera json value        secolor = "#096cc1";